# How to pass value from one tabbar View item to other?

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I have a button in News Tab, And I want pass value to Competition Tab by any way.

But the problem is not passing correct value.

**My code is-**

//NewsViewController

```
@IBAction func fullStndngAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //I Tried this
        let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
        prefs.set(true, forKey: "isFromNewsView")

        //I Tried This as well
        let whereFrom  = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LatestNewsDetailViewController") as? LatestNewsDetailViewController
        whereFrom!.isFromNewsView = true

        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1

    }
```

But always I am getting false in competition view.

**Image description-**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the following solutions depending on each condition.

case 1: If your ViewController is embedded in a navigationController try this: -

```
if let competitionsVC = self.tabBarController.viewControllers?[1].children.first as? CompetitionViewController {
 competitionVC.isFromNewsView = true
 self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Case 2: If your ViewController is not embedded in navigationController

```
if let competitionVC = self.tabBarController.viewControllers?[1] as? CompetitionViewController {
 competitionVC.isFromNewsView = true
 self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Explanation: For case one since the VC which you are looking for is embedded in navigationController then you have cast down the way to it's child which is the VC you are looking for. For case two there is no navigationController so you cast direct to the VC you are looking for, ie.. no need to find child like on case 1.

Comment: Value of type 'NewsViewController' has no member 'viewControllers'

Comment: Oops, I fixed my answer you need to access the tabBarController of that view. Please check my answer then try again.

Comment: Nothing happen, It not enter in if let condition

Comment: I think since you said you want to pass your value to CompetitionVC then you should cast to it. Just in case I ranamed the TargetVC to CompetitionVC and edited my answer so that you can double check your target VC if it is indeed CompettionVC at that index 1.

Comment: My both view controller(News and competition) are navigationController embedded.

Comment: For that case then option 1 above should be able to find that target VC if it is indeed located at index 1 of TabBar because I use that method on one of my apps. Another solution might be to use a tidy way of setting NSNotification or other options.

Comment: Oh, I just make it optional. And its worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad that it worked, happy coding :)